# Git Not Ignoring Sub-Directories

Tags: git

I had `static/` in the `.gitignore`, which successfully ignored the entire directory. I now want to stage everything in it except `static/vendor`.

I thought that having `static/vendor/` inside `.gitignore` would do it. However, it does not. When I submit `static` for staging, all files from inside `static/vendor` still end up being staged alongside others that I actually want.

Is there a trick to this? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe putting `/static/vendor/**` into gitignore will do the trick… although i am afraid `git add` might ignore gitignore

Comment: I think `*/static/vendor/*` did the trick. That is weird. Not sure how that differs from just `static/vendor/`.

Comment: do you have any directories in `vendor`? if so, i am not sure if the single-asterisk solution will work for the items in them

Comment: maybe you should have ignored `/static/vendor` and not `/static/vendor/`

Comment: maybe there is some bug in `git add`/`gitignore` handling that causes only-if-directory ignored directories not to get ignored

Answer (score 4):

The `.gitignore` rules are a little weird.  (For that matter, the name `.gitignore` is a little weird, but forgivable: a better name would be `.git-do-not-complain-about-some-files-that-are-untracked-and-do-not-automatically-add-them-in-that-case-but-this-file-has-no-effect-on-files-that-are-tracked`, or something equally unweildy.)

Each line in `.gitignore` has one of a few general forms:

- comments and blank lines get ignored;
- lines with `!` are do-not-ignore rules; and
- the remaining lines are ignore-rules.

This lets us dispense with the first type entirely, and think about the second and third type of line using one set of rules, with the "do not ignore" applied at the end.  So now we're down to the following sub-rules:

- lines can contain a name with *no* slash at all: `foo`, or
- lines can contain a file name with a leading slash, but no embedded slash: `/leading`, or
- lines can contain a file name with a trailing slash, but no embedded slash: `trailing/`, or
- lines can contain a file name with leading *and* trailing slash, but no embedded slash: `/leadandtrail/`, or
- lines can contain a file name that *does* have an embedded slash, combined with any or all of the above: `has/slash`, `/has/slash`, `has/slash/`, and so on.

(Lines can also contain various glob characters, which for now, let's not worry about!)

To keep this explosion of sub-categories simpler, we want to group them into just two crucial sub-categories, which I will call *anchored* and *un-anchored*.  Along a separate axis, we want to group them into two *other* crucial sub-categories, which I will call *slash-suffixed* and *not-slash-suffixed*.

An *anchored* name is any name that either *starts with* a slash or *contains an embedded slash* (or both).  So `/leading` and `has/slash` and `/has/slash` are all anchored, but  `foo` and `trailing/` are *un-anchored*.

A *slash-suffixed* name is any name that *ends* in slash.  This one final slash is removed as soon as the name is categorized as slash-suffixed.  So `trailing/` is slash-suffixed but then treated as if it were just spelled `trailing`, and `has/slash/` is also slash-suffixed and treated as if it were just spelled `has/slash`.

Hence the entry:

```
vendor/
```

is slash-suffixed but un-anchored, while:

```
static/vendor/
```

is both slash-suffixed *and* anchored.

(A name like `a/b//` is slash-suffixed and anchored and treated like `a/b/`, and a name like `b//` is slash-suffixed and anchored and treated like `b/`.  The extra slash left over is just a bad idea: don't do it.  I'm not sure what actually happens!)

Now that we've categorized the names as anchored or un-anchored and slash-suffixed or not-slash-suffixed, we can describe how the gitignore rules work for them:

- Any slash-suffixed name matches a partial path name if and only if that partial path name represents a directory/folder.  So `vendor/` matches the *directory* (or folder) `vendor`, but not a *file* whose name component is `vendor`.  Without the slash-suffix, the name matches *both* a file *and* a directory.
- Any *anchored* name matches only the components of file name that *start from the same directory in which the `.gitignore` file was found*.  That is, given an anchored `vendor`, we'll exclude `vendor` in *this* directory, but not `a/vendor`, `b/vendor`, and so on.  Given an unanchored vendor, we'll exclude `vendor` in this directory *and* `a/vendor` *and* `b/vendor` and so on.

This is why adding `static/` in front of your `vendor/` changed its behavior: it went from un-anchored to anchored, so that it began to act like `/static/vendor/` (which would of course do the same thing: it's anchored in two ways, but the only thing that matters is that it is anchored).

Adding `**/` in front enables the (still-anchored!) string `static/vendor/` to match `a/static/vendor`, `b/static/vendor`, and so on.  You didn't need the `**/` in front when `vendor/` was un-anchored.

#### An alternative

<s>Note, by the way, that you could remove the `vendor/` entry entirely from *this* `.gitignore` file (wherever it is) and create a `static/` entry in `vendor/.gitignore`, creating that file if necessary.  That would be un-anchored but slash-suffixed.  It would match the directory `static` in that directory or any sub-directory *of* that directory.</s> Edit: Oops, this was backwards: you would want a `vendor/` in the `static/` directory.  But the general principle applies here.

(The main, or perhaps only, drawback to this is that you will have created or altered a file in this particular sub-directory—and, of course, that you might need to do it in multiple sub-directories.)